# Automating Rally Task

Tags: rally

In my project i am using Rally tool to manage the project task.
I need to export the task list from rally and need to provide as an input to an SSIS package in order to generate some reports.
Can anyone suggest whether we could use any API to automate  the export of task list.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest the following option in Python using pyral. Hope it will work for you.

```
from pyral import Rally

SERVER = 'RALLY_SERVER'
USER = 'USERNAME'
PASSWORD = 'PASSWORD'
WORKSPACE = 'WORKSPACE'
TARGET_PROJECT = 'PROJECT'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rally = Rally(SERVER, USER, PASSWORD, workspace=WORKSPACE)

    project_req = rally.get('Project', fetch=True, query='Name = "%s"' % (TARGET_PROJECT))
    project = project_req.next()

    tasks = rally.get('Task', fetch=True, query='Project = %s' % (project.ref))

    for task in tasks:
        # do anything with tasks
        pass
```

However, you can use it with any suitable programming language for you. Please refer to WSAPI documentation (Task section):
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/